# Cloud Firestore document .get() and .where() functions not recognized

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am building a permissions-based auth system with Firebase authentication and Cloud Firestore and I am having trouble checking for a user doc at login. The app is built using Angular 6 and angularfire2.

The idea is that once a user logs in the app will check to see if a user document has been created for the user. If not, it will create a user doc and fill it with default permissions and user information.

Here is my code and the two functions I have tried:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { User } from './../models/user.model';
import { PermissionsService } from './permissions.service';

import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from 'angularfire2/auth';
import {
    AngularFirestore,
    AngularFirestoreDocument,
    AngularFirestoreCollection,
} from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
    usersCollection = null;
    user: Observable<User>;

    constructor(
        private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
        private db: AngularFirestore,
        private permissionsService: PermissionsService,
    ) {
        this.usersCollection = db.collection('users');
        this.user = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
            switchMap((user) => {
                if (user) {
                    return this.db
                        .doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`)
                        .valueChanges();
                } else {
                    return of(null);
                }
            }),
        );
    }

    loginGoogle() {
        const provider = new auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
    }

    loginFacebook() {
        const provider = new auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
        return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
    }

    loginTwitter() {
        const provider = new auth.TwitterAuthProvider();
        return this.oAuthLogin(provider);
    }

    oAuthLogin(provider) {
        return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then((credential) => {
// My first attempt using .where to find a doc with matching email
// This gives an error saying .where() does not exist 
            const docExists = this.usersCollection.where(
                'email',
                '==',
                credential.user.email,
            );
            if (docExists) {
                console.log('User logged in');
            } else {
                console.log('user does not exist');
                this.createUser(credential.user);
            }
//My second attempt using .get() to find a doc with matching uid
//The id of the doc matches the uid of the auth user by design
//This gives an error saying .get() does not exist
            // this.usersCollection
            // .doc(credential.user.uid)
            // .get()
            // .then((docSnapshot) => {
            //  if (docSnapshot.exists) {
            //      console.log('User logged in');
            //  } else {
            //      console.log('user does not exist');
            //      this.createUser(credential.user);
            //  }
            // });
        });
    }

    createUser(user) {
        console.log('creating user');
        const newUser: User = {
            uid: user.uid,
            email: user.email,
            photoURL: user.photoURL,
            displayName: user.displayName,
            roles: {
                member: true,
            },
            permissions: this.permissionsService.memberPermissions,
        };

        this.usersCollection
            .add(newUser)
            .then((docRef) => {
                console.log('added new user');
                newUser.uid = docRef.id;
                docRef.set(newUser);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log('Error adding user: ' + err);
            });
    }

    logout() {
        this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
        this.user = null;
    }
}
```

Here are the errors that are thrown:

> zone.js:192 Uncaught TypeError: _this.usersCollection.where is not a function

and

> zone.js:192 Uncaught TypeError: _this.usersCollection.doc(...).get is
>   not a function

I'm pretty new to firebase and especially new to Firestore (I guess everyone is) and I can not find anything in the documentation of angularfire2 or firebase that would indicate why I can't do this.

Please help me understand why these functions are not viewed as valid.

*Also, if you have any tips or comments on how I might go about this whole auth process in a better way feel free to add a comment. This is my first attempt at creating an auth service like this.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> // This gives an error saying .where() does not exist:

Well that's because `.where()` does not exist on type `AngularFirestoreCollection`. You're assinging it by `this.usersCollection = db.collection('users')` in the constructor.

Querying a collection can be done this way:

`const docExists = this.afs.collection<User[]>('users', ref => ref.where('email', '==', credential.user.email));`

But this will not solve your issue. In previous statement, `docExist` will also be an `AngularFirestoreCollection`, and the check on `if (docExists) {` will always be true. So what your looking for is a way to check if a document exists based on a query:

```
private oAuthLogin(provider: any) {
    return this.afAuth.auth
        .signInWithPopup(provider)
        .then(credential => {
            const usersCollection = this.afs.collection<User[]>('users', ref => ref.where('email', '==', credential.user.email));
            const users = usersCollection.snapshotChanges()
                .pipe(
                    map(actions => {
                        return actions.map(action => {
                            const data = action.payload.doc.data();
                            const id = action.payload.doc.id;
                            return { id, ...data };
                        });
                    }),
                    take(1));

            users.subscribe(snap => {
                if (snap.length === 0) {
                    console.log('user does not exist');
                    this.createUser(credential.user);

                } else {
                    console.log('User logged in');
                }
            });
        });
}
```